# How to get a character while inside a loop without stopping in the loop?

Tags: c, loops, character, wait

Hello I am new to C programming but I am making a menu for a game. I have a fish in ascii art displayed and it gets moved one character over every .5 secs. I accomplish this by a simple loop and it keeps on going across the screen then when it reaches the end, the fish is cleared and then it gets repeated again. Now while this animation is going on I would like to prompt the user for an input, however when I do that with getchar or scanf for example the fish loop waits until I press something and the animation stops until I press a key. Coould someone please shed some light on my problem??

Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with any of the standard input methods. You're going to either have to use something like ncurses, or put the terminal into raw mode and do some pretty fancy manipulations. I have no idea what platform you're on, but raw mode is difficult under Linux, and even harder under Windows, so I'd stick with a library if you can.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato, that isn't polite.

Comment: Hey Chris, can you go into more detail about why you would use this instead of threads?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: the big issue is that a terminal isn't something that multiple threads can easily share. Even though threads make it *possible* the instant a user starts typing it's going to get all garbled and weird. At the bare minimum you'd need to do something like turn off echoing. And yes, threads would indeed make the job easier. HOWEVER they are NOT required if you do it this way, and frankly given the task threads seem a bit heavyweight.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I guess in both cases user will be learning something useful for future ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of [Threads](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/C++Programming-HOWTO-18.html).

To understand threads think of how your computer works. If your computer ran without threads, you would not be able to run multiple applications at the same time. Threads allow for multiple parts of a program or interface to run at the same time without depending on eachother.

In your case, you will want a thread for the input and a separate thread for the animation. Thus allowing both to run separately.

Comment: Though please note that multi-threading is an advanced topic that beginners better avoid until they know the programming language and OS well.